# Sending React-Webam Screencapture to Node.js Server and Saving to File

Tags: node.js, express, base64

I am trying to send react-webcam capture to server and in doing this, am using JSON.stringify() to send the base64 output from the react getScreenshot() to the express server and then converting the base64 to buffer and then to file. But after that i still get an error when openning the image that the image file is not supported. I have also tried to use sharp and i get an error that the input from the buffer contains unsupported image format. below is my client code and server code.

```
const capture = React.useCallback(async () => {
const imageSrc = webcamRef.current.getScreenshot();
await sendData(imageSrc);


 const sendData = async data => {
// console.log(data);
const image = JSON.stringify(data);
const res = await axios({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/images',
  data: { name: image }
});

console.log(res.data);
```

};

on the server this the code.

```
const data = JSON.parse(req.body.name);
const buff = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');
await sharp(buff).toFile('output.png')
await fs.writeFileSync('felix.jpeg', buff);
```

example of data that i am sending to the server is just a base64 string. Below is an example. The string is too long for me to paste here so that is why I am pasting a screenshot instead . When this base64 reaches the server, i need to covert to buffer and the to file or pass it to sharp.js. And that is where i am having the problem
[image]

Comment: can you please show examples of `data`? (add it to the question)

Comment: Hello, @jps i have made the edit

Comment: thanks. So this is the exact content of the variable `data` and you try to decode that, right? But that's not a base64 string, but a data uri containing a base64 string. You need to cut off everything from the beginning including `...base64,` and only convert starting from `/9j/...`

Comment: Let me try that out and give you feedback. I think it is going to work on

Comment: glad to know it works